# Does anything interesting come out of this identity?

Tags: soft-question, complex-numbers

Students often make the mistake of writing the following:

$$\frac{1}{a+b} = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

However, after doing a bit of algebra, it turns out that the above has solutions defined by:

$$a=be^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}+2n\pi i},\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
and:
$$a=be^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}+2n\pi i},\ n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Using the original equation, it can be shown that:

$$(e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}+1)^{-1} = e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}+1$$
$$(e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}+1)^{-1} = e^{-i\frac{4\pi}{3}}+1$$

Are there any interesting applications of these identities?

Comment: .. if a student  knows what is the exponential form of complex numbers  that he never made  such  mistake with  those fractions.

Comment: I was explaining the motivation behind the identities/equalities.

Comment: There is no need to the $+2n\pi \operatorname{i}$ in your expressions. You're just adding a full turn, which doesn't change the number.

Comment: I don't know... Would you consider [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501176/a-question-by-ramanujan-about-a-relational-expression-of-a-triangle) to be interesting ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian That is just the kind of problem I was looking for. How would I go about applying the above to a problem like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$, a cube root of unity.  Since $(\omega - 1)(\omega^2 + \omega + 1) = \omega^3 - 1 = 0$, and $\omega \ne 1$,
$$
\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0,
$$
and so we obtain the identites:
$$
\omega + 1 = - \omega^2 = - \omega^{-1}
$$
and
$$
-\omega = \omega^2 + 1 = \omega^{-1} + 1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left( \omega + 1 \right)^{-1} = \omega^{-1} + 1.
$$

Comment: Very cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The cube roots of unity are special in various ways - because they are quadratic they are constructible in the Euclidean sense (just as an equilateral triangle is constructible). They also have special properties because of their quadratic character (Hardy & Wright "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" gives the old-fashioned version of this - and surprising depth for an old-fashioned treatment). The cube roots of unity emerge from the equation you give as perhaps initially unexpected. But once identified, the quadratic field they define is well known.

Comment: Thank you for posting a constructive answer. I'll look into that